# 9 axes motion shield

Tags: arduino, motion-detection

I am having some issues getting stock code to compile for my 9 axes motion shield. I have a github [repository](https://github.com/infinitefoamies/Arduino_INS) with all of the motion libraries I have, the example code, and the error messages I am getting.

I am using Arduino 1.7.1 IDE on Windows 7 64-bit.

I have tried using sample code for the sensor instead of for the shield and could not get that to compile either. I have tested example code built into the IDE to ensure that I can compile something and I was even able to interface with my Arduino MEGA 2560 with said code.

I have searched Google and Stack exchange a fair bit and have not managed to come up with any solutions.

The main error I can not figure out is:
"
C:\Users\LJI_eric\Documents\Arduino\sketch_mar20a\sketch_mar20a.ino: In function 'void setup()':

sketch_mar20a:63: error: 'OPERATION_MODE_NDOF' was not declared in this scope

mySensor.setOperationMode(OPERATION_MODE_NDOF);"

OPERATION_MODE_NDOF is a mode that is defined in BNO055.h and is an array of operation modes. I tried several other modes to no avail.

I would appreciate any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

On line 84, 87 and 91 you have made a new line inside a string. You can not do that on the Arduino. If you want to break a string up in more lines you should end the string where you would break it, and start the string again on the new line, like this.

```
Serial.println("Move the device around and then place it at one position.\n"
"Change the threshold and duration to increase the difficulty level.");
```

Then you should change `OPERATION_MODE_NDOF` to `BNO055_OPERATION_MODE_NDOF`

Comment: Yes.. The last line i wrote ;)

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry not sure why I did not see that line.